# Как получить все ID элементов?

Tags: php

На странице есть неопределенное количество ссылок вида:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show(10512672)">
    <img src="https://site.ru/info.png">
</a>
```

Мне нужно получить все ID которые находятся в **show(10512672)**
т.е. **10512672**

Буду благодарен за помощь! Подозреваю здесь не обойтись без регулярки...

Comment: Очень дажй обойтись — взять [любой html-парсер](https://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) и пройтись в цикле по нужным тегам, вытащив атрибуты onclick

Comment: если id формируется гдето (а не пишется ручками) то лучше при формировании страницы записать в какой-то массив все id-шники и после уже вытягивать с него

Answer (score 0):

Если данные ссылки находятся в DOM, то средствами js и jquery можно сделать так к примеру:

```
var arrLink =$('a');
var result = [];
arrLink.map(function(index, item) {
    var attr = item.getAttribute('onclick');
    result.push(Number(attr.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')));
});
console.log(result);
```

Иначе как в первом комментарии, парсите данные и пробегайтесь так же циклом, вытаскивая id

Comment: В тегах указан PHP, поэтому автор предполагает решение для него.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show(1111111111)">
        <img src="https://site.ru/info.png">
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show(22222222)">
        <img src="https://site.ru/info.png">
    </a>
HTML;
$array = array();
preg_match_all( '/onclick="show\(([^"]*)\)"/i', $html, $array ) ;
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $array[1] ) ;
```